# Large block of HTML in a PHP block

Tags: php, html

I'm using PHP to make my page more dynamic through query passing however I have a big chunk of HTML code that needs to have dynamic content inside but I don't know how to go about doing that without printing every statement:

One part in HTML:

```
<div class="review">
<p>
<img src="http://www.cs.aub.edu.lb/hsafa/cmps278/hw2/rotten.gif" alt="Rotten" />
<q>Expect no intelligence or subtlety here, but if you're willing to put up with the        sheer ridiculousness of it all, you might enjoy wallowing in Bekmambetov's shameless   exhibition of narrative lunacy and technical fireworks in this movie.</q>
</p>
</div>
<div class="personal">
<p>
<img src="http://www.cs.aub.edu.lb/hsafa/cmps278/hw2/critic.gif" alt="Critic" />
Frank Swietek <br />
<span class="italic">One Guy's Opinion</span>
</p>
</div>
```

The above code is for a single review however there could be any number of reviews which I am already taking a count of but I am also changing the image, quotes and text for all the reviews.
Is there a way of including all the tags without printing them all?

Comment: Convert it to a template.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

Answer (score 1):

The regular way is to "close the php tag" and then reopen it after the HTML:

```
// php code here 
?><html code goes here><?php
// php code here
```

However, there are a couple other ways.  One is to use include.

```
// php code here
include('template.file.php');
// php code here
```

and inside your html code, you use have something like this:

```
<htmltag><?= $php_value ?></htmltag>
```

You can even use include within a function.

Alternatively, you can use a template system like Handlebars, Mustache, or Twig.  Or you can just continue to build large strings, which is what I do.  I set up templates, merge them with data to produce strings, and then emit the strings.  The main thing I gain from using the templating system is that I can save up the strings to emit them at the end, and thus, have the ability to alter the HTTP header before my output is sent.  If I used include() or code blocks, the code is emitted immediately, and I cannot modify HTTP header values.

Additionally, by building up the strings, I can save them to files and use these precalculated chunks to improve the site's speed.

Comment: Closing the tag `?>` and then reopening `<?php` also works in functions.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
//PHP code section
$wolrd = 'world';
?>
We are back in HTML
Hello <?= $world /* and some PHP echoing with a 'short tag' on same line with HTML*/ ?>
```

Suggested reading:

- http://www.smarty.net/ (I'm not a fan but you should be aware of it)
- [MVC - Model - View - Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)

Answer (score 0):

You should only be using PHP to print your dynamic content

`<img src="<?php echo $image_url; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image_alt; ?>" />`

Answer (score 0):

You can close PHP and start it again at any point

```
<?php
$string = "hi";
?>
<p>Lot's of HTML</p>
<?php
echo $string;
?>
```